# Содержит ли сгенерированный оператор перемещения оператор delete? C++

Tags: c++, перемещение

Если мы явно определяем оператор перемещения, то мы обязаны перед самим перемещением освободить динамическую память в классе, если таковая имеется, иначе произойдет утечка памяти:

```
struct Example {

    int* m_ptr;

    /*...*/

    Example& operator=(Example&& another) {
        // Если тут не освободить память, то после перемещения
        // В классе не останется указателей на эту память
        delete m_ptr;
        m_ptr = another.m_ptr;
        another.m_ptr = nullptr;
    }

}
```

В связи с этим мне стало интересно как ведет себя сгенерированный компилятором оператор перемещения. В интернете я без проблем нашел правила генерации оператора, но я не нашел того, как он выглядит внутри и освобождает ли он память. Если применяет, то есть ли для этого какие-то правила? Не может же сгенерированный оператор применить delete для переменной-не-указателя, это вызовет ошибку

Comment: Конечно, нет. Он просто вызовет перемещение (где сможет) для всех полей, только и всего.

Comment: @Harry то есть если у нас в классе есть указатель на динамическую память, то мы не можем полагаться на генерацию оператора и обязаны определить свою версию с оператором delete?

Comment: Задумайтесь на минуту — откуда генерируемый оператор может знать, на что указывает этот указатель? На выделенную через `new` память или на какой-то адрес глобальной переменной, например? Да, вдогонку — и обнулять поля он тоже не станет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию он выглядит примерно так:

```
Example &operator=(Example &&another) noexcept
{
    m_ptr = std::move(another.m_ptr);
    return *this;
}
```

То есть ничего не удаляет, а просто вызывает `=` для каждого поля.

Для сырого указателя `m_ptr = std::move(another.m_ptr);` эквивалентно `m_ptr = another.m_ptr;`.

---

Совет раз - используйте [copy&swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/2752075). В 99% случаев он позволяет не думать, что писать в `operator=`:

```
Example &operator=(Example other) noexcept
{
    std::swap(m_ptr, other.m_ptr);
    return *this;
}
```

Такой оператор может работать и как копирующий (если есть копирующий конструктор), и как перемещающий (если есть перемещающий конструктор). И он выдерживает бросок исключения из конструктора.

---

Совет два - никогда не вызывайте сами `new` и `delete`, если только вы не пишете свой контейнер или умный указатель.

Используйте стандартные контейнеры и умные указатели.

Comment: ага, мув конструктор копирует переменные класса:) он их перемещает. Другое дело, что для указателя перемещение==копированию.

Comment: классно, два плюса этому вопросу показывает, что мув сементику у нас люди знают очень плохо. Очень жаль

Comment: @KoVadim только сейчас заметил, что у него копирование. Ну опечатался человек) Я так понимаю что он, возможно, не понял вопрос и написал про оператор копирования, поэтому он и написал про copy&swap, ведь для перемещения эта идиома не имеет смысла

Comment: возможно, возможно.

Comment: @KoVadim Только сейчас понял, про что был ваш первый комментарий. Здесь move все равно ничего не делает, но для ясности вернул его.

Comment: @ComeInRage Почему не имеет смысла для перемещения? Не опечатался, просто не стал писать мув, который ничего не делает.

Comment: да, я и написал о том, что здесь конкретно move ничего не поменяет. Но вот только никакого акцента на этом не было.  А фраза "То есть ничего не удаляет, а просто вызывает = для каждого поля." все ещё немного странная

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ну разве задача перемещения - не избежать полного копирования? А copy&swap делает именно полное копирование, а потом частичный обмен данными. Для перемещения copy&swap не имеет смысла. Поправьте меня, если я не прав

Comment: реализация перемещения через копирование вполне законно. Другое дело, что ответ HolyBlackCat немного уводит в сторону.

Comment: @KoVadim но как перемещение может вообще работать через копирование? Допустим у нас есть вектор, который является переменной-членом класса. Если у нас в конструкторе перемещения этого класса будет copy&swap, то в аргумент функции будет полностью скопирован класс вместе с std::vector, что приведет к потере производительности. Разве это не так?

Comment: для pod типов копирование и перемещение это одно и тоже. Переместить int или указатель - это просто его скопировать. Но для вектора это конечно не то и через copy-swap его не реализовать (можно просто через swap). Поэтому, я и пишу в комментах об этом.  +5 голосов только подтвержает то, что мув семантика это суперсложно

Comment: @KoVadim *"для вектора это конечно не то и через copy-swap его не реализовать"* Почему это? Copy&swap (т.е. `operator=` из моего ответа) отлично подходит и для него тоже. Заметьте, он не всегда копирует, он может делать и move + swap.

Comment: @ComeInRage *"Разве это не так?"* Не так. Почему класс обязан копироваться в аргумент? Он может быть туда перемещен.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat действительно. Я не подумал, что если у класса есть конструктор перемещения, то при передаче r-value ссылки произойдет не копирование в аргумент, а перемещение... Такая запись действительно путает) Но это довольно полезная информация, спасибо